# Connecting Symfony app to Google Cloud SQL (App Engine Deployment)

Tags: php, symfony, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

### **Problem :**

Can't establish a PDO connection from my symfony App, deployed on Google App Engine, to a Google Cloud SQL database

### **Setup :**

Followed [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-symfony-on-appengine-standard), which does seem a little outdated, on deploying a Symfony/PHP App to App Engine:

**1. Cloud SQL Database**

```
MySQL instance, server_version=5.7, public ip_address
```

**2. Symfony**

```
Version 5.2
```

*config/packages/framework.yaml*

```
framework:
  secret: "%env(APP_SECRET)%"

  session:
    enabled: true
    handler_id: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\PdoSessionHandler
    cookie_secure: auto
    cookie_samesite: lax
    gc_maxlifetime: 36000

  php_errors:
    log: true
```

*config/services.yaml*

```
services:
  # ...

  Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\PdoSessionHandler:
    arguments:
      # - "%env(DATABASE_URL)%"
      # you can also use PDO configuration, but requires passing two arguments
      - "mysql:dbname=[INSERT_DB_NAME]; host=[INSERT_HOST]; port=[INSERT_PORT]"
      - { db_username: [INSERT_USER], db_password: [INSERT_PW] }
```

*config/packages/doctrine.yaml*

```
doctrine:
  dbal:
    url: "%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%"
...
```

**3. App Engine**

*app.yaml*

```
runtime: php74

env_variables:
  APP_ENV: prod
  APP_SECRET: [INSERT_APP_SECRET]
  DATABASE_URL: mysql://root:DB_PASSWORD@localhost?unix_socket=/cloudsql/INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME;dbname=symfonydb

handlers:
 ...
```

### Different Configuration & Errors :

1. Choosing to use the *ENV_DATABASE_URL* or the
   *PDO_configuration_arguments* in `config/services.yaml` doesn't seem to affect the outcome. Neither does adding or not the port 3306.
2. I'm connecting with the root user of the Google Cloud MySQL
   Instance with a password.

***1. localhost***

```
PDOException:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

  at vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Session/Storage/Handler/PdoSessionHandler.php:443
  at PDO->__construct('mysql:dbname=[INSERT_DB_NAME]; host=localhost;', 'root', '[INSERT_PW]', array())
```

***2. 127.0.0.1***

```
PDOException:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

  at vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Session/Storage/Handler/PdoSessionHandler.php:443
  at PDO->__construct('mysql:dbname=[INSERT_DB_NAME]; host=127.0.0.1;', 'root', '[INSERT_PW]', array())
```

***3. Cloud SQL Public IP***

```
PDOException:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out

  at vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Session/Storage/Handler/PdoSessionHandler.php:443
  at PDO->__construct('mysql:dbname=[INSERT_DB_NAME]; host=[INSERT_PUBLIC_IP]; port=3306', 'root', '[INSERT_PW]', array())
```

### Update

After updating packages to symfony 5.3, it magically started working. But I'm not totally convinced this was the actual solution